# Prevent space between flex items in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to build a calendar component. I used flex display to align dates horizontally, but there seems to be a space between two items at certain places. I have changed the background color to black to visualize the space. I want to remove that space. I have attached the image and the styles of parent and content container. I have marked the vertical space appearing in the image. Thanks in advance. Open the code in mobile view to see the vertical space.

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4deda5

Change to mobile view and view this link :
https://react-4deda5.stackblitz.io

Comment: The links do not show the Award column and hence no extra space.

Comment: @MikeLischke I removed the header, so if you inspect the element, you can see an empty div.

Comment: In the fiddle I see no extra space between the Sun column and the empty column. I colored the last 3 divs in the first row with red and the touch each other with no space between them.

Comment: @MikeLischke Please do open that in mobile view like iPhone X or anything, you can see.